# Kustomize doesn't seem to find helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kustomize, snap

I'm trying to incorporate a helm chart into my kustomize setup. So I have added it to my `kustomization.yaml`:

```
...
helmGlobals:
  chartHome: ../test/vault
helmCharts:
  - name: helm-vault
    valuesFile: ../test/vault-values.yaml
...
```

When I try to build this on command line I get this error:

```
$ kustomize build --enable-helm infrastructure/vault/dev
Error: accumulating resources: accumulation err='accumulating resources from '../_base': '/home/tel/Private/Sources/domstolene@github.com/k8s-applications/infrastructure/vault/_base' must resolve to a file': recursed accumulation of path '/home/tel/Private/Sources/domstolene@github.com/k8s-applications/infrastructure/vault/_base': unable to run: 'helm version -c --short' with env=[HELM_CONFIG_HOME=/tmp/kustomize-helm-821391692/helm HELM_CACHE_HOME=/tmp/kustomize-helm-821391692/helm/.cache HELM_DATA_HOME=/tmp/kustomize-helm-821391692/helm/.data] (is 'helm' installed?)
```

The message suggests that `helm` might not be installed; however when I run it it is readily found:

```
$ helm version -c --short
v3.10.1+g9f88ccb
```

Also; my kustomize version:

```
$ kustomize version
v5.0.1
```

What might be the reason?

**Update**

I tried to follow this very nice guide: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/kustomize/v4.1.0/examples/chart.md

I still get same error message even though I used the `--helm-command` argument to give kustomize the absolute path to the helm binary `/snap/bin/helm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem like `kustomize` have a problem with `snap` in some way. I downloaded a binary version from the [helm release page](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases) and specifying that binary with `--helm-command` seems to remove the problem entirely.

**Update**

It wasn't this entirely neither. So far it seems like the helm-binary have to reside under my home-directory. See https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/5094#issuecomment-1473459361

**Updatier**

It seem to be snap after all; although not the helm installation. The kustomize binary was also installed by snap. I removed it and installed a binary version instead and then everything worked like a charm.

It could be related to kustomize installed as regular snap-application and helm installed as "classic" snap-application.